# How to open the file in link in MS edge using jquery or javascipt?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui

Below is the code handled, to open  file link in the browser.
Here when I try to load the file link in the MS Edge browser.the file is not opening when
I click on the link from MS Edge browser
.this is working for InternetExplorer need to handle in code for MS Edge also.

```
    try {
        var workbook = new jQuery.ig.excel.Workbook(jQuery.ig.excel.WorkbookFormat.excel2007);
        var l_ddlTarget = jQuery("#ddlTarget").igCombo("value");
        jQuery.ajax({

            url: baseURL + '/MarginalImpact/ExportCTRMData/',
            type: "post",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                argTarget: l_ddlTarget,
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(jQuery(errorThrown.responseText).filter('title').text());
            },
            success: function (result) {
                jQuery("#myModalExport").modal('hide');
                var l_FilePath = result;
                if (l_FilePath != null && l_FilePath != "")
                    l_FilePath = l_FilePath.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
                jQuery("#lbExport").attr("href", "file:///" + l_FilePath);
                jQuery("#lbExport").text(l_FilePath);
                jQuery("#fakeloader-main").addClass("black-screen");
                jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css("background-color", "#e8e8e8!important");;
                jQuery("a").css("background-color", "#e8e8e8!important");
                try {
                    jQuery("#dialogFilterSectionMI").igDialog("destroy");
                }
                catch (e)
                { }
                jQuery("#dialogFilterSectionMI").igDialog(
                    {
                        modal: true,
                        headerText: "Click on below link to open the file",
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        height: "200px",
                        width: "600px",
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,

                        showCloseButton: true,

                    });
                jQuery(".ui-igdialog-close-icon").css("background-color", "#c2c2c2");
```

Comment: I don't see any C# code. What are you trying to accomplish in C#?

Comment: Actually trying to get the jquery or JS code to open the file in the link,this is the part of asp application

Answer (score 0):

Opening files / folders via file:/// from a webpage protocoll is no longer supported in modern browsers (Edge, Chrome, etc.) due to security reasons.

For some use cases MS edge has introduced a new protocoll (viewinfileexplorer) that for opening files via webDAV, but not sure if this helps you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#configureviewinfileexplorer

Comment: whether the file in the link can be opened in the file explorer.